# Create Firebase Console Dynamic Links through REST API

Tags: firebase-dynamic-links

Is there a way to create Firebase Dynamic Links in the console using a provided API, without using the "New Dynamic Link" button?  I want to automate this process for multiple white label apps that share the same dynamic links, and manually creating each one is very tedious.  Below is the button I **don't** want to use.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes , you can create a Dynamic Link  through make an HTTP POST request to the shortLinks endpoint, by specifying the Dynamic Link parameters directly.

Follow this document : [Create Dynamic Link through Rest API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/rest#create_a_short_link_from_parameters)

Comment: Hey Randima, I'm looking for the specific ability to create a dynamic link together with choosing the suffix, and having it appear on the console as a result.